# Etherscan now using No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is presen

Tags: react, cors

First post here.    I've been building quite well making a game on Ethereum but mainly just been trying to get the basics right and concentrating on the deposit and withdraw section of my dapp.    Using Metamask players and deposit and withdraw ethereum.
As a player, on the 'Activity' page you can see all your transactions.   This is collected from etherscan using Axos in a React application.
When you make a new transaction (deposit or withdraw) using the web3 object a 'reciept' is created and a transaction ID is obtained.   Using this txnid I can see this transaction being confirmed / indexed on the blockchain and there is a little flag to say that it's currently being confirmed by other nodes.  After a while the txn flag turns to Success and then this txn is seen.
I use this data to make a placeholder transaction so the user can varify this is happeneing.
I also save this info to a database in case the user refreshes the page.  The placeholder will load and they can click a link to go to etherscan to see this txn being confirmed.
Up until now this has worked like a dream, but I'm now suddenly getting the following annoying error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x36f22855535a44b19efa3a72872a9fb96515d3f620998644747a3a7d108c730a' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Before this code was working fine.

If I throw this into a browser it's working because there is no cross browser.

My question is how come it worked for 2 months and now etherscan is not allowing this behaviour?   Have they just decided not to allow unconfirmed transactions to be viewed from anyther application ?

Please shout if you need any more info or get in touch.

Many thanks

Graham

Comment: It seems you were accessing directly to an explorer page `https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/xx`. They may have changed who can access them. They provide a separate api `https://docs.etherscan.io/v/rinkeby-etherscan/api-endpoints/stats` for some details. Etherscan is a closed source third party provider they can change its behavior at any time.

Comment: Hi Ismael.   That link really helped me.   I found the perfect api end point to facilitate this properly without bouncing off a proxy server.   Thank you.